# GWT Flextable and CSS aligning rotated text along the bottom of the cell

Tags: css, gwt

I am trying to align text in a GWT flextable, the text is rotated -90 degrees, so that it lines up across the bottom of the cell. An example of the code I am using is (all cells in this row are the same height):

```
Label lblLeadership = new Label("Leadership Course");
            lblLeadership.setStyleName("gwt-Rotate");
            flexTable.setWidget(0, 1, lblLeadership);
            flexTable.getCellFormatter().setHeight(0, 1, "200px");
            flexTable.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(0, 1, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
            flexTable.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(0, 1, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
```

However, this results in the text extending past the bottom of the cell as per:
[image: Incorrect allignment]
If I use:

```
flexTable.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(0, 1, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

The the text aligns in the middle; however, this does not look very good.

If I use:

```
flexTable.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(0, 1, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_TOP);
```

Then the text extends past the top of the cell into the heading "Pack Overview" and menu.

My CSS is:

```
.gwt-Rotate {
    color: Black;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

Is there a way to get the text to align nicely along the bottom of the cell please?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `transform-origin` (IE >= 9) and `transform: translate`.

Example
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azLmbg

Comment: Hi @PapaStan, Thank you for this advice. However, this moves rotated text to the far left over the "Name" heading. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Is the text `text-align: center;` ?

Comment: Hi @PapaStan, I should not have been so quick to dismiss your original solution. After a lot of playing around I found that "transform-origin: 325% 50%;" was the answer. Everything now lines up nicely. Thank you very much. Regards, Glyn. ps., to answer your question I am using "text-align: left;".